# npm package to use with angular to create a tree like structure?

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular 4 and I want to implement a tree like structure in my app. I noticed there are tons of packages for this, but I don't know which one to use.

I tested `angular2-tree-component` and the tree structure is ok, but I want to display some html content for each node when clicked and I'm not sure this can be done using `angular2-tree-component`.

Comment: You can improve your question by adding an example of what you are trying to achieve (in my mind i can image few different types of tree like structures). Plus you can list plugins you already considered, and some thoughts about them.

Comment: Also `most appropriate` plugin question, may fall under: primarily opinion-based type of question, and can be considered off-topic here

Comment: Maybe this https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/templates can help with displaying html content

Comment: I don't want to customize the nodes, I want to display some content in the page when the node is clicked, like  a `single page application.`

Comment: @annie https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/events